# ".(" in Jetpack Compose Text causes newline

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In this Jetpack Compose code the result of the first Text composable has the parenthesized text on a new line:

```
Column {
    Text(text = "2.(0123456789)",
            modifier = Modifier
                    .width(60.dp)
                    .padding(start = 5.dp))
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier . padding(20.dp))
    Text(text = "2.0123456789",
            modifier = Modifier
                    .width(60.dp)
                    .padding(start = 5.dp))
}
```

[image]

This does not happen if I remove the ".", or if I remove the "(".

Comment: Not sure why it would be happening, but have you tried escaping the characters with \

Comment: Your width is `60.dp`, which means the regular rules of line breaking apply, same as with the rest of Android. What makes you think it is doing anything wrong?

Comment: I had tried escaping. As for the rules of line breaking, how do the "." and "(" factor in?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Sorry, I'm new to Android, starting out with Compose. I did not run into this in JavaFx. I will look into the rules and how to get what I want Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `modifier = Modifier.width(60.dp)` which applies a fixed width to your `Text`.

Use [**`Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout#intrinsic-measurements) in your `Column`

```
Column(Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)) {
    Text(text = "2.(0123456789)",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 5.dp))
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier . padding(20.dp))
    Text(text = "2.0123456789",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 5.dp))
}
```

[image]

If you want to specify a limited width you can use [`Modifier.requiredWidthIn`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#requiredwidthin) to specify a width between mindp and maxdp and [`maxLines = 1`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#text) in the `Text`.

Something like:

```
Column(Modifier.requiredWidthIn(0.dp , 75.dp)) {
    Text(
        text = "2.(0123456789)",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 5.dp),
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis

    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
    Text(
        text = "2.0123456789",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 5.dp),
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
    )
}
```

Otherwise you apply the `Modifier.requiredWidthIn(0.dp , 75.dp)` to the Text components instead of the Column.

```
Column(Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max)) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .requiredWidthIn(0.dp, 75.dp)
        maxLines = 1
    )
    //...
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .requiredWidthIn(0.dp, 75.dp)
        maxLines = 1,
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep the Text a limited width. In any case, even with IntrinsicSize, once the max width is reached (for longer strings between the parentheses), it still breaks after the '.'. I have a feature request in for the desired behavior, but pending that, it seems you can get it to work by inserting "zero width no-break spaces" (\uFEFF) at the appropriate points.

Comment: @RickRegan If you want to specify a width just add maxLines = 1 in your text. I've updated the answer.

Comment: But then that truncates the line after the ".". I am looking for a fixed-width, multi-line text, that only breaks at the width and not according to any other rule. I think the only way to get what I want at this point is to use non breaking spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ain't with character escape. It is the fact that you have applied a fixed small width and because the order of the modifiers matters, the width is further trimmed by 5dps of your padding

EDIT: I am not exactly sure, but I think it could be because of the fact that Text inherently supports the feature where a textholder would display a single word in one line if it can. When you insert a special character like a period or a bracket, it considers the rest of the string to be a new sentence (grammatically), and observing it's length, calculating that it will not fit in the same line, starts a new line. Then the length is still bigger but there is no option but to start a new line. Hence, the rest of the phrases go all the way to the end, then start on s new line on reaching maximum capacity. Try inserting just a single character after the period or the bracket. I do not think that it will insert a new line since there will be room to insert the entire statement (in this case, just a single character). When I started typing, I thought it was not for sure, but now, I am almost convinced that this is the case.

Comment: I want a fixed width, as per the discussion on the other answer. It looks like this is just something Android does not currently support directly.